# no file on upload to django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

Update: none of the 2 answers below work. When I use request.FILES["file"] I get a key error.

Using django rest framework I'm trying to upload a pdf file but the request comes in and there is no file. I am trying to upload the file from Postman. The get request works. Any help very much appreciated.

Here is my view

```
@api_view(['PUT','GET'])
def upload_pdf(request):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        myfile = request.POST.get('file')
        print("myfile === {}".format(myfile))

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response({"message": "Hey there at least this works!"})
```

Output: myfile === None

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the code but with postman.
I couldn't figure out how to use postman and nobody suggested anything about postman.
so I just tested it with a curl command
This works perfectly...

```
curl -XPOST -i -F file=@dir/to/test.pdf http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload_pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

In Django, all uploaded files will end up in `request.FILES`, not in `request.POST`. That is why you're not seeing that file in post data.

Comment: Thanks @GwynBleiD file = request.FILES['file'] gives me a key error

Comment: Any other ideas @GwynBleidD?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser

class Fileupload(APIView):
   parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
   def post(self, request, format=None):
     file = request.FILES['file']
     if 'file' not in request.data:
          raise ParseError("Empty content")
     model_obj = YourModel.objects.get_or_create()

     model_obj.myfile.save(file.name, file, save=True)
```

hope it helps

for more details refer [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser)

Comment: Hi Thank you but  file = request.FILES['file'] gives me a key error

Comment: @user3250052 you need to pass **file** in your key

Comment: I do have file in the key. I selected it from the dropdown menu. you can only see it when you hover the mouse pointer over it